# How to show Navigation Bar using NavigationExperimental

Tags: react-native

Here's how I'm currently trying:

```
render() {
    return (
      <NavigationCardStack
        direction={'horizontal'}
        navigationState={this.state.navState}
        onNavigate={this._handleAction.bind(this)}
        renderOverlay={(props) => (
          <NavigationHeader
            navigationState={props.navigationParentState}
            position={props.position}
            getTitle={state => state.key}
          />
        )}
        renderScene={this._renderScene.bind(this)} />
    )
  }
```

Taken from here: https://github.com/ericvicenti/navigation-rfc/blob/master/Docs/Navigation.md

Is there something I'm missing? The app loads fine and it shows the first scene, but no navigation bar on top of it (in either Android or iOS).

Comment: What is your React native version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If yours react native version is 0.32 or above change renderOverlay to renderHeader. There was breaking change in 0.32. Where renderOverlay was changed to renderHeader and it seems all docs haven't been updated yet. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.32.0